# On a child theme - Please enter credit card details error message

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm getting this error message when I'm trying to set up the Stripe payments:

"Please enter your credit card details. Developers: Please make sure that you are including jQuery and there are no JavaScript errors on the page.

There's no errors on the page. When I switch to the parent theme, this works. I Don't know what else to try here. i have read a few posts on this issue but non solves it for me.

Comment: If you open your browser console do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: No there's no errors.